# Twig: how to apply a filter to a translation string

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-filter

Lets say I have this:

```
{%trans%}html.string{%endtrans%}
```

that prints this string

> This is a string with some `<i>`html`</i>` tags.

I want to apply the Twig filter `striptags` to obtain this:

> This is a string with some html tags.

As you can see I have "removed" the *italic* tags.

So I need a way to do something like:

```
{%trans%}html.string|striptags{%endtrans%}
```

Obviously this is not the correct way of applying filters to the translated string, so, how can I do this?

Comment: I never used Twig tags to do it but do you have a particular reason to not use `{{ html.string|trans|striptags }}` or `{{ 'html.string'|trans|striptags }}`?

Comment: No, i don't... I simply forgot this notation! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{"html.string"|trans|striptags}}
```

note that you always have to apply the `trans` filter first.